# Phabricator and MAMP PRO Configuration? Keep getting a 403

Tags: apache-http-server, php

I currently have MAMP PRO installed, where I run local WP installs. I am trying to install Phabricator.

I followed all the [directions](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/configuration_guide/) on their site, but I can't get it to work.

I have all apache modules required loaded.
I setup my domain as phab.dev in MAMP PRO. That adds the correct entries to my host file.
I then edited httpd.conf with

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName phab.dev
    DocumentRoot "/Users/developer/Sites/phabricator/webroot"
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/rsrc/(.*)     -                       [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico   -                       [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /index.php?__path__=$1  [B,L,QSA]
</VirtualHost>
```

I also tried adding the same options above to httpd-vhosts.conf. No luck.
When I type phab.dev on my browser I ended up getting a 403, because no index file is available. That makes sense because the index.php file is inside the webroot folder. That means that the RewriteRule is not redirecting to webroot as it was supposed to.

What are other things that I can check for? How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Initially I thought it was a permissions problem, but all files have the write permissions.

Comment: You can set up `LogLevel` in apache configuration to get more detailed log. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#loglevel